# Why does pressing a command button multiple times results in an increase in List size in IE but not in Firefox?

Tags: jsf-2, tomahawk

I am facing a strange problem. Consider:

Here is a datatable,

```
 <t:dataTable value="#{details.beanList}"
                var="detailsVariable" 
                 preserveDataModel="false" id="someId"
                 rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

                <h:column >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:panelGrid align="center">
                            <h:outputText value="LINE NO." />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <h:panelGrid align="center">
                            <h:outputText value="(#{listInOtherBean.listSize})" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
                </h:column>
```

and there is a `command button` above this datatable that refreshes data(gets the latest list from the database.)

When I press this button and keep on pressing before that page refreshes as response to the form submit request, this value `#{listInOtherBean.listSize}` will increase by an unknown factor in IE whereas it will be fixed in Firefox.

Attached Screenshots:

***1)*** For `Mozilla Firefox`, 11876 is the list size which is reflected correctly and it will not change no matter how many times a user presses this button and keep on pressing before that page refreshes as response to the form submit request.

[image]

2) For `Internet Explorer`, considering 3 times that button was pressed,

[image]

Do notice one thing that `11876 * 3 = 35628 != 37943`, that the reason why I aforementioned increase by an `unknown factor`.

**NOTE:**
It would be of no benefit if you imitate the problem like this,

```
<h:form id="ngliform">
    <h:commandButton action="#{refreshResetBean.refreshData}"
        id="refreshDataBtn" value="Refresh Data" style="margin-top:8px"
        onclick="document.getElementById('ngliform:resetFilterBtn').disabled=true;" />
    <br />
    <h:dataTable value="#{refreshResetBean.list}" var="listItem">
        <h:column >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:panelGrid align="center">
                    <h:outputText value="LINE NO." />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid align="center">
                    <h:outputText value="(#{refreshResetBean.listSize})" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{listItem}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

and the managed bean,

```
    List<String> list;

    public RefreshResetBean() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(i.toString());
        }
    }

    public String refreshData() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public Integer listSize;

    public Integer getListSize() {
        listSize = list.size();
        return listSize;
    }
```

It will be visualized with the correct list size in all 3 browsers, `IE, MF, Chrome` & the list size won't change no matter how many times button is pressed.

[image]

The website is not developed by me and there is too much code to get through. But I am amazed why the difference in `IE and MF` & I want the case to as reflected in MF?

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Kukeltje: Absolutely wrong, it's tomahawk.

Comment: ok, tag added for you

Comment: What others? PF? RF? Plain jsf datatable? Then state so and add all this info to your question. And make an MCVE then, so others can try to reproduce. E.g. the button that needs to be pressed according to your text is not shown anywhere...

Comment: and add jsf implementation version info